# How can I use the Box-Mueller method to generate generic normal distributions?

Tags: probability, random

Using the [box-mueller method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), we can generate standar normal distributions from two uniformly distributed random variables.

However, how do we use this method to generate normal distributions with means and variances other than 0 and 1 respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If X is a standard normal random variable (mean $0$ and variance $1$), then $\sigma X+\mu$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. So, just apply this transformation to the samples obtained from the Box-Mueller method.